Modules Android Studio - My moduleA cannot use a class from moduleB
I'm trying to access moduleB from moduleA, but even though I reference the module using module settings, Android Studio just adds the same line every time I try to sync the build.gradle.
image 1
image 2
I little detail: this two modules are Multiplatform.
image 3
I tried cleaning, rebuilding the project, and using 'Invalidate Caches' in Android Studio, but it didn't resolve the issue.
Is it possible to use a multiplatform module in another multiplatform module?

Please write your code in the question rather than using images.

To import another module in a Kotlin multiplatform project, write it like this in your build.gradle.kts file:
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":data"))
}

(with "data" being the project name).

Thanks for your help Simon, I tryed this solution but the build..gradle repeat the line again. I tried put this code in domain module but not working.

If you want more help solving it, best to share the the text of the settings.gradle, the root build.gradle, the project build.gradle files and clearly write out in text the project structure where those files are located

Now I updated my Android Studio (Iguana pach 2), and I tried incluid a KMP module and it get worse... all build.gradle of module cannot sync... for gods sake...
